# VB MyParameters Class Appears to Stop

Tags: vb.net

I'm passing values to and from a Background worker. To do this I'm using the following class to store the variables:

```
Class MyParameters
        Friend _QueryStr As String
        Friend _Value_CreatedDate As Object
        Friend _AccountID As Object
        Friend _Last_Login As Object
        Friend _Motto As Object
        Friend _Bio As Object
        Friend _pFavourite_Game As Object
        Friend _pFacebookLink As Object
        Friend _pInstagram As Object
        Friend _pTwitterLink As Object
        Friend _pTumblerLink As Object
        Friend _pYoutubeLink As Object
        Friend _lblpYoutubeLink As String
        Friend _lblpTumblerLink As String
        Friend _lblpTwitterLink As String
        Friend _lblpInstagram As String
        Friend _lblFacebookLink As String
        Friend _lblpFavourite_Game As String
        Friend _lblBio As String
        Friend _lblMotto As String
        Friend _lblLast_Login As String
        Friend _AccessCode As String
        Friend _TargetUGPoints As String
        Friend _Stream As New MemoryStream()
        Friend _Image As Byte()
        Friend _DoB_Value As Object
        Friend _DoB As Date
        Friend _Years As Integer
        Friend _Months As Integer
        Friend _Cautions_Value As Integer
        Friend _Cautions As Integer
        Friend _Bitmap As New Bitmap(_Stream)
        Friend _Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source =" & My.Settings.ServerIP & ";Initial Catalog=Atlas;Integrated Security=False;User=" & My.Settings.UserName & ";Password=leaders132;")
        Friend _MyCMD As New SqlCommand(_QueryStr, _Con)
    End Class
```

And I'm calling the background worker like this on a forms load event:

```
 Private Sub cdb_ProfileViewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Loadinglbl.Visible = True
        SpinningProgress1.Visible = True
        MsgBox("Starting MyParamters")
        Dim m As New MyParameters
        MsgBox("My Parameters set to m")
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(m)
    End Sub
```

However, the application doesn't seem to reach the background worker. There's no freezing or errors, it simply does nothing. I remain in control of the form like the background worker is working, but I dont think it's even starting because it doesn't run any msgbox's. For example, I've included a `Msgbox` in my code to let me know which stage the code has reached. It works if I place it **before** `Dim m as New Parameter`, **but not after**.

My Background worker, note I've omitted my code as it's lenthy:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim m As MyParameters = DirectCast(e.Argument, MyParameters) 'Convert the generic Object back into a MyParameters object
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        e.Result = m

'Do some time-consuming work on this thread

end sub
```

My WorkerCompleted Event, also without code:

```
  Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim m As MyParameters = DirectCast(e.Result, MyParameters) 'Convert the generic Object back into a MyParameters object
        MsgBox("Reached Worker Complete")

        'Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.

end sub
```

My BW Public Class Code:

```
   Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    Private Delegate Sub ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

And the Public Sub responsible for the BW:

```
  Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = False
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = False
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub
```

Is there anything that's jumping out at you? As I say, I feel it's something in my `Class MyParamters`.

Comment: you have several illegal fields in that class (and several that are not a good idea at all).  For instance, the bitmap and SQLCommand are going to throw and exception.  When that happens in the FormLoad you wont know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The Load() event unfortunately swallows your exception.  Move that code to the Constructor or the Shown() event and the problem becomes apparent:

```
    Friend _Bitmap As New Bitmap(_Stream)
```

You can't create a Bitmap from an Empty Stream...

Minimum code to reproduce:

```
Public Class MyParameters
    Friend _Stream As New MemoryStream()
    Friend _Bitmap As New Bitmap(_Stream)
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim M As New MyParameters
End Sub
```